# Disable overscroll in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, touch, mobile-safari

How can I prevent overscroll in Safari iOS?
I would use the touch gesture for navigate on a site but I can't.

I tried this:

```
$(window).on('touchstart', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

But  in this way I disabled all gesture, infact I can't zooming with pinch-in and pinch-out.

Any solutions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

This way will allow scrollable elements while still preventing the overscroll in the browser itself.

```
//uses document because document will be topmost level in bubbling
$(document).on('touchmove',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
//uses body because jquery on events are called off of the element they are
//added to, so bubbling would not work if we used document instead.
$('body').on('touchstart','.scrollable',function(e) {
  if (e.currentTarget.scrollTop === 0) {
    e.currentTarget.scrollTop = 1;
  } else if (e.currentTarget.scrollHeight === e.currentTarget.scrollTop + e.currentTarget.offsetHeight) {
    e.currentTarget.scrollTop -= 1;
  }
});
//prevents preventDefault from being called on document if it sees a scrollable div
$('body').on('touchmove','.scrollable',function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: great solution!  worked for me.  remember to put the "scrollable" class on all divs you want to scroll.

Comment: This works for me as well. Thanks for saving my life from hell!

Answer (score 7):

This *Should* be the easiest way to accomplish this:

```
$(function() {
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }, false);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Best.

Comment: This works perfectly, retains scrolling on divs and minimal code!

Comment: I did...can only do it once!!

Comment: @NeedHelp, this blocks my scrollable divs also. Did you do something extra to keep them scrollable?

Comment: @Yves Van Broekhoven...I used this custom scroller http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ but even without it I still get scrollable divs...

Comment: @Yves Van Broekhoven...Have a look at http://130.95.21.121/museum/search.php and choose the System checkbox then select Digestive system and All in the dependant menu.  Search results will fill the LH div and it's scrollable.  The page can't be moved due to Todd's code above.

Comment: so, @YvesVanBroekhoven, try removing the `$(function(){...});` from around my no-overscroll code. that's the only problem i see right off hand; you've got two document-on-ready handlers as result. I'm running late, but will take a closer look later today, and try and help you.

Comment: Thx @Needhelp, sorry for the late response. Haven't figured it out so far. Keep you posted.