# How to get Safari on iOS8 to hide the toolbars on an iPhone 4/4S/5/5S

Tags: safari, ios8

On iOS7.1 you can hide Safari's toolbars with something like

```
  <meta name="viewport" 
        content="width=device-width, 
                 target-densitydpi=160dpi, 
                 initial-scale=1.0, 
                 maximum-scale=1, 
                 user-scalable=no, 
                 minimal-ui">
```

This is great. If the user scrolls or click the top of the window the toolbars appear. if they click the content the toolbars disappear

[image: iOS 7.1 Safari]

But on iOS8 clicking either the top **OR THE BOTTOM** brings up the toolbars and they NEVER GO AWAY. This completely ruins my webapp

[image: iOS 8.0 Safari]

Is there a workaround for both of these issues?

1. Make it so clicking the bottom does NOT bring up the toolbar. In my web app I have buttons at the bottom.
2. Make it so clicking the connect removes the toolbar. With so much of the screen taken up by UI chrome my app doesn't have space to work

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest read this post [iOS 8 removed "minimal-ui" viewport property, are there other "soft fullscreen" solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889100/ios-8-removed-minimal-ui-viewport-property-are-there-other-soft-fullscreen) and the question should be more specific (iOS8 only in old iOS devices <=5S), because, in iOS into the **iPhone6** and **iPhone6 Plus** have a different behavior, it's not possible to open the toolbar if you tab in the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Sigh.... My issue is I have controls on the screen. iOS8 covers them with it's bars and there's no way to detect it. If the screen starts with a minimal UI then when the user clicks top or bottom the window.innerHeight changes and I can adjust. But if the user refreshes the page the page and every measurement I've been able to find tells me that I've got the fullscreen but the bars are still there and so I have no way to adjust. The only thing I can think of is check for 5s+iOS8 and assume the bars are always there :(

Comment: Yep, there are no way to "fix" that problem even if you load the apple web page the behavior is the same, I would guess why apple has removed the minimal-ui is due is not needed anymore in the new iPhones 6 and of course, they have broken all websites that are viewed using Safari in iOS8 with 4S to 5S. I have the same issue and I don't have any valid fullscreen solution for me (games). The unique solution is adapt your site to that screen in only that range of devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the frosted bar at the bottom with four tools (send page, multiple window option, etc.) then sometimes if you hold your finger on the middle of the screen and scroll up (moving the page up) about one inch then that bar disappears.