# iOS8 disable address bar resize - minimal ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

Safari under iOS8 is causing a issue resizing address bar.

I have a fullscreen background image and some elements positions fixed from bottom and top of div that is 100% width and 100% height

on iOS7 if inside this box i have some content that cause scrolling safari address bar did not resize ( or i did disabled some way ) now with iOS8 while scrolling safari hides address bar and change viewport size and this make my content resize.

Is it possible to disable this feature via javascript or css?

Comment: You might want to look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889100/ios-8-removed-minimal-ui-viewport-property-are-there-other-soft-fullscreen

Comment: What i want is that safari doesn't switch to minimal ui, from the approved answer i would say that this is not possible (not sure they was testing beta or final iOS8).I can only detect size and resize my contents, correct?