# Is there a way to make my mobile web app to go fullscreen on Safari on iOS 8+

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, fullscreen

I'm new to Phonegap and mobile development in general, right now I'm working on an app and the users must be able to see the entire web app without the address bar in browsers (because of space and appearance). I found little options like these three: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/

The window.scroll trick doesn't work anymore so there's only a way (I think), going fullscreen. I managed to do it in Chrome, with a node module, also when users add the web app to home screen and open it from the icon, it opens in fullscreen both in Android and iOS.

The problem is, I need it to go fullscreen (or hide the address bar) without the user doing too much, for example, in Android the first tap on the web app make the browser go fullscreen (without the user necessarily adding the web to home screen or doing anything more), in iOS Safari there was a way until iOS 7, the "minimal-ui" option for the viewport, but that does not work anymore, I found something that may replace the minimal-ui function: [iOS 8 removed "minimal-ui" viewport property, are there other "soft fullscreen" solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889100/ios-8-removed-minimal-ui-viewport-property-are-there-other-soft-fullscreen) and tested that npm module called Brim, but it doesn't work for me because if you are in the "fullscreen" mode and slide from one page to another, it goes out of the "fullscreen" mode, also in the normal mode (with the address bar), you cannot scroll or use the inputs or anything, and I dont want to force users to go fullscreen.

In conclusion, is there a way to hide the address bar on iOS 8+ Safari or go fullscreen in a easy way like Android (just tapping or something) but allowing the user to get out of the fullscreen mode and still being able to use the web app normally?

Comment: Can you explain how you're loading your app with PhoneGap? Building a PhoneGap app you wouldn't even get an address bar since its just a plain WebView.

Comment: Yes, but only if you open the built app. In my case, users will be able to download the built phonegap app, or access to the web app via https, like a normal mobile website.