# Allow the user to collapse the mobile browser's address bar on website that adjusts to viewport size

Tags: css, mobile-browser, address-bar

Mobile browsers like Chrome on iOS usually collapse the address bar when the user scrolls down. However, I have a page that adjusts the size of its content to the viewport (basically the content has CSS `height:100vh`). It's an image gallery so there is no point in it being any bigger than the viewport. Consequently, there is no possibility for the user to scroll. Yet, the page of course can make use of additional space, as this allows displaying the content bigger, providing a better user experience (especially since mobile phone screens are already so tiny).

I wonder if there is a way to maintain the ability to collapse the address bar to the user also on a page that cannot be scrolled. Alternatively, it would be a workaround if the collapsing could be triggered programmatically for example using JavaScript.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/

Comment: This isn't natively possible since iOS8 unfortunately. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26884561/1848468) for a workaround (a but dated but should still work).

Comment: @pedram None of the solutions/hacks provided in that doc are working on current iOS…