# VueJs Nuxt PWA not rendering on iphone

Tags: ios, vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

My vuejs nuxt portfolio(https://gunjankadu.com/)is not opening on ios phones but working flawlessly on all other devices. On IOS devices only a red spinner is shown and nothing more.
What can be done?

A script "tag.js" took time to load, which I have currently disabled but still not working.

Comment: Do iPhones even support PWA? Last time I checked, it didn't. Can you check with the official vuejs documentation? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: It looks like there is a script that doesn't resolve.  Tags.js timed out after about 3 mins.   Though the site works in chrome, it doesn't load completely and the loader is visible on the tab.    IOS is probably waiting for this to resolve before it loads the PWA

Comment: @retrograde i removed the script "tag.js" still the website is not loading

Comment: I think I would need to see code before I could make another guess.

Comment: I'm having a similar situation with an app I'm developing. It's supposed to have PWA support, but I'm having this issue directly while using the webapp. It loads fine the first time but If I manually change the route in the browser, the new page shows the nuxt loading animation and never stops. Don't know what could be happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look on your application and found out two problems.
First was about regular expressions, It seems Safari doesn’t support look behind yet. One alternative would be to put the / that comes before in a non-captured group, and then extract only the first group (the content after the / and before the #).

```
/(?:\/)([^#]+)(?=#*)/
```

And second is about The minimal-ui viewport property that you can find out more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889100/ios-8-removed-minimal-ui-viewport-property-are-there-other-soft-fullscreen)

Answer (score 0):

Look at all your js/vue files especially in store. And see if any variable used is not imported. Nuxt in SPA mode doesn't detect those kind of errors and surprisingly the UI gets stuck on loading only on iOS. Very weird but scratched my brain over it for a day.