# How to go full screen on Safari/iOS landscape mode?

Tags: javascript, ios, orientation, fullscreen, landscape

I have build a small game that run on canvas.

I want the game to run on full screen.

I follow the example given in this very helpful guide.
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/full-screen-web-apps--mobile-7509

But on **Safari/ iPhone** when I rotate the device to landscape mode part of the display get cut off by address bar.

The way I go to full screen is by selecting the "Hide Toolbar" option.

This is how it looks when I don't hide the tool bar and goes to landscape mode
[image]

This is how it looks when I hide the tool bar and goes to landscape mode from portrait mode
[image]

You can see part of the canvas get cut-off by the tool bar

Now if I hide the tool bar in landscape mode it does look correct. But if I go to portrait mode and come back to landscape mode screen again get cutoff.

Following is the code I used

```
  <div id="canvasHolder" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;background-color: transparent;">
  <canvas id="GameCanvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" tabindex="0"></canvas>
  </div>

<script>

function hideAddressBar()
{
  if(!window.location.hash)
  {
      if(document.height < window.outerHeight)
      {
          document.body.style.height = (window.outerHeight + 50) + 'px';
      }

      setTimeout( function(){ window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 50 );
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){ if(!window.pageYOffset){ hideAddressBar(); } } );
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", hideAddressBar );

</script>
```

I have seen many post regarding similar issues. But I can't seems to get it to work in my case.

Can anyone provide some advice on how to fix this issue   ?

Comment: If you click on AA button on Safari address bar you get a menu. In that you have the option called "Hide Toolbar". Which hide the tool bar

Comment: In portrait mode if I hide the tool bar the screen looks right. When I rotate to landscape mode the tool bar comes back. The problem is now the tool bar is hiding part of the canvas.  as in picture 2

Comment: YES, but that is not the problem. part of the canvas get cut off.

Comment: I have. The problem is it only works on browsers running on Android

Comment: I found following link; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889100/ios-8-removed-minimal-ui-viewport-property-are-there-other-soft-fullscreen
which explains similar process. Don't have enough information to get it working

Comment: They refer to this website https://fornacestudio.com/ which works perfectly on iPhone fullscreen

Comment: Hi guys any help you can give on this?